# Search API on Datastore with frequently changing data

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

Datastore entities have the following fields:

- id
- created
- user_id
- not_unique_id
- name
- description
- number

I want to be able to perform a Full-text search on name and description. In order to do this we need to create Google Search Api documents from the Datastore entities.

However, the datastore data has the following attributes:

- Data for an user is removed 12 hours after its added.
- On user demand, the data for the user is removed and new data is added.
- The not_unique_id is a third-party id that should be used to combine related entities in the Search Api because we only want one per search.
- When a user submits new data it will be +- 1000 entities at a time.

The biggest issue I have is preventing to have Google API documents that reference Datastore entities that do not exist anymore. (Not exist as in the not_unique_id does not appear in the Datastore anymore)

I would like to see some concepts, guideliness, ideas and tips so I can verify I'm on the right way. Thanks!!

**Solution in progress:**

Below is the routine to keep the Search API in sync with the Datastore. CreateUpdateDelete are executed on user request. Read is executed on App request. The Cron job will use Delete to keep the Search API in sync with the Datastore.

**Datastore Entities**

id = user_id

ancestor = not_unique_id

```
| ancestor | id | created | name | description | number |
| 19385020 | 1  | 1234567 | Foo  | Qwerty      | 63     |
| 19385020 | 2  | 1234567 | Foo  | Qwerty2     | 12     |
| 19385020 | 3  | 1234567 | Foo  | Qwerty      | 74     |
```

**Search API Documents**

```
| not_unique_id | name | description |
| 19385020      | Foo  | Qwerty      |
```

**Create**

1. If ancestor+id combination already exists, go to Update.
2. User data is inserted into the Datastore.
3. Search documents are created based on ancestor (not_unique_id). Name and description of the Document is the most common name that appears in the Entity group.

**Read**

1. Full-text Search API Query on name/description to obtain the not_unique_id.
2. Query Datastore for entities with ancestor == not_unique_id and number > 0.
3. TODO what if no entities exist anymore for one or more of the found not_unique_id's? I am expecting a certain amount of results for pagination.

**Update**

1. Update datastore entity.

**Delete**

1. Set number to 0 of datastore entity.

**Cron**

Fetch all Entities where number == 0 or created < 12 hours ago. Remove Document if last decendant Entity is about to be removed. Remove Entity.

Comment: Search API always has *eventual* consistency, the only way to get strong consistency is to use ancestor queries. Can you implement your search by only using datastore?

Comment: What kind of searches you need to perform on name and description attributes? Full text search with stopwords and with ranking, or just looking for equal matches?

Comment: I need Full-text search for name and description including stopwords and ranking. Where stopwords are the least important.

Comment: Hi Pim, Do you know about nonrel-search project? I think it could be the answer to what you're looking for. Have a look at it https://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/nonrel-search

Comment: Hi Mario. If using the Google Search API is not an option, I think I prefer running Sphinx in a VM Instance of the Compute Engine because of previous experience. But thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Suppose you'd do this with the search API, then you will always compose a query that has an equal condition on the not_unique_id ? Right ?

Comment: Yes. Maybe create a single Document for Entities grouped by not_unique_id. I will try to update my question soon with current architecture and bottlenecks.

Comment: @PimReijersen - that is exactly what i was thinking. make the non_unique_id part of the ancestor key, do a preliminary query on the datastore before you 'might' get stale results from the search api.

Comment: Updated the question. Point 2 of Read is what you meant with a preliminary query right?

Comment: And maybe it makes sense to move Point 3 of Create to Cron. So the CRUD is only for the Datastore and Cron for sync with Search API.

Comment: Hi Pim, after looking at your question I believe it would be possible to do it with Datastore + Search API. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, using a Cronjob to keep everything in sync its theoratically possible. I will submit a solution when I have it working and tested on a larger dataset. Biggest problem is showing lists because of the eventual consistency of the Search API. But every other action can be performed in a safe way by checking the Datastore entry in question before performing the action.